# Eager side effect (printf) in ocaml

Tags: ocaml

Newbie question:

Say I have a function `do_sth` that is very slow, and it is applied to range 1 to n. I want to print the result of `do_sth i` when it is looping. How to do this? A naive attempt fails as the values will only be printed after the whole loop:

```
let rec loop i =
  if i>1000 then 0
  else
    let fi = do_sth i in
    (
    Printf.printf "%d %d\n" i fi;
    fi + loop (i+1)
    )

let f_sum = loop 1
```

Comment: That should be `let rec loop`. And you might want to use `flush stdout` after each `printf` to get output displayed immediately, instead of getting it in seemingly in one go after the loop.

Comment: instead of calling `flush` function one can use the `%!` specificator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Effects in Ocaml *are eager* by default: the language is said to have eager evaluation<sup>1</sup>, as opposed to so called lazy languages like *Haskell*.

The result you are witnessing is due to buffering done by output primitives for `stdout`. Simply flushing the buffers with `Pervasives.flush stdout` or `Pervasives.flush_all ()` will provide the desired behaviour.

Also, you may optimise your function by making it tail recursive: instead of doing the sum after the recursive call, accumulate the result in a function parameter:

```
let loop i =
  let rec loop r i =
    if i>1000 then r
    else
      let fi = do_sth i in (
        Printf.printf "%d %d\n" i fi;
        flush stdout;
        loop (r+fi) (i+1)
      )
  in loop 0 i
```

<sup>(1) However Ocaml also supports lazy evaluation of some sort through the module `Lazy`, but evaluation has to be triggered explicitely in certain situations.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

How about you do the following instead :

```
let fi = do_sth i in
let () = Printf.printf "%d %d\n" i fi in
fi + loop (i+1)
```