# Ocaml performance vs go

Tags: performance, go, ocaml

I'm trying to implement utf8 decoding in Ocaml as a learning project. To check the performance I'm benchmarking against the go standard library.

This is the go code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
    "unicode/utf8"
)

func main() {
    start := time.Now()

    for i := 0; i < 1000000000; i++ {
        utf8.ValidRune(23450)
    }

    elapsed := time.Since(start)
    fmt.Println(elapsed)
}
```

When I run it, I get:

```
go build b.go
./b
344.979492ms
```

I decided to write an equivalent in ocaml:

```
let min = 0x0000
let max = 0x10FFFF

let surrogateMin = 0xD800
let surrogateMax = 0xDFFF

let validUchar c =
  if (0 <= c && c < surrogateMin) then
    true
  else if (surrogateMax < c && c <= max) then
    true
  else
    false

let time f x =
    let t = Sys.time () in
    let _ = f x in
    let t2 = Sys.time () in
    let diff = (t2 -. t) *. 1000. in
    print_endline ((string_of_float diff) ^ "ms")


let test () =
  for i = 0 to 1000000000 do
    let _ = validUchar 23450 in
    ()
  done

let () = time test ()
```

Output:

```
ocamlopt bMl.ml -o bMl
./bMl
2041.075ms
```

The ocaml equivalent basically copies the implementation of the go stdlib from https://golang.org/src/unicode/utf8/utf8.go#L517

Why is the ocaml code so much slower?

Comment: 1. Don't ask, profile. 2. Use reliable performance measurements instead of your own.

Comment: To expand on the @Volker's comment: you might be measuring weather on Mars with such approach. Use the benchmarking facilities of the Go's `testing` package and whatever similar stuff OCaml provides.

Comment: I can't program OCaml but is it possible to make it a bit more "imperative" to make sure both calls to Sys.time happen *right before and right after* executing the for loop? (I recall Haskell had some `$` thingy to force eager evaluation; what about OCaml?)

Comment: Well, OK, looks like OCaml [is eager](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27731806/720999).

Comment: Also, if you write `then true else false`, you have to learn a lot of things about programming before doing any benchmark by yourself.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answers all. Will investigate how this should be done properly. @PatJ fwiw, writing `then true else false` results in better performance vs returning `(0 <= c && c < surrogateMin) || (surrogateMax < c && c <= max)`.

Comment: That...makes no sense at all.  Is OCaml not a lazy evaluation language or something?

Comment: No, OCaml is not a lazy evaluation language.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As observed you should be using `Unix.gettimeofday` to measure wallclock time. You can use `Sys.opaque_identity` however to prevent OCaml from optimizing useless operations away, and you can use `ignore` to 'return unit' instead of the usual value of an expression. Altogether:

```
let time f x =
  let t = Unix.gettimeofday () in
  ignore (Sys.opaque_identity (f x));
  let t2 = Unix.gettimeofday () in
  ...

let test () =
  for i = 1 to 1_000_000_000 do
    ignore (Sys.opaque_identity (validUchar 23450));            
  done
```

Note the `i = 1`, which you want if you want exactly one billion iterations (a figure I couldn't tell was one billion before adding the underscores, which OCaml allows). Previously you were measuring one billion plus 1 iterations. Not that that was the difference.

Your verbose definition of `validUchar` did not benefit its performance any. Please write a microbenchmark and confirm that.

Finally, after making the changes suggested above and writing your `validUchar` in a more natural manner, I get an OCaml runtime that's identical to the Go runtime ... after adding -O3 to the ocamlopt arguments. And it's easy to confirm that this isn't due to the compiler 'optimizing the operations away' -- commenting out the `f x` call in `time` results in runtimes of 0 or near-0 values like 1.19e-06.

Don't be discouraged by the responses you got to this question. But *do* expect that any kind of "why does this benchmark have this result?" question to a programming forum will be answered similarly.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the elaborate response! Can you maybe share your code? My verbose version seemed a little bit faster than the "idiomatic" writing style in the one billion call range. https://pastebin.com/80RtW9xX

Comment: @Seneca compile with -S to inspect the intermediate assembler. The explicit if/else version has branches right where you'd expect. Since your input is always the same, the same branches are always taken. Which leads to, not 'magic' compiler optimization, but 'magic' optimization by the CPU itself. Keywords: pipelining, branch prediction.

Comment: Hmm interesting, didn't know about it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 5):

The `Sys.time` shouldn't be used for time measurements, as it returns a processor time, not the real time. The `Unix.gettimeofday` function is a much better candidate. Alternatively, you can time your program from the shell using the `time` command.

As a side note, benchmarking is hard, and it is very easy to get misleading results. In your particular case, if you will turn on optimizations both compilers will remove the computations, since they are not used and will produce code that does nothing, and thus is rather fast :)

Comment: Thanks, still got a whole lot of learning to do, I'll investigate further.

Comment: Unexpected compiler optimizations are a HUGE source of erroneous benchmarking results.  There's a whole host of suggestions that go along with Golang benchmarking for avoiding undesirable compiler optimizations during the tests.